# Increase the count in the database , Spring boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I am working on a project using Spring boot and hibernate. I want to record the number of times an item is executed.

The android app will have a button to execute. As soon as user clicks the button. I want to update the database count for execution, and for every execution I want to increment the count.

Below is the get and post controller. When the user posts details I want to increment the count in the table by the number of times user clicks the button and posts.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/item", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class ItemController {
    @Autowired
    private ItemExecRepository itemExecRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.NEVER)
    public Iterable<ItemExec> getAllItems() {
        return itemExecRepository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void itemExec(@RequestBody ItemExec itemExec) {
        itemExecRepository.save(itemExec);
    }
}
```

Any help on this will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Class project? If so, that's fine, but discuss what you already tried and where you're stuck, not just "I want to ...."